# Xamarin: Can we use Ghostscript to display PDF on android

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin, ghostscript

I have a problem rendering PDF on Android pre-SDK 21. I know SDK 21, android have PDFRender to render PDF but for pre-SDK 21 I have no way to generate the PDF apart from either using third party application or using google doc.

There is a ghostscript i have used before on MVC project. It generate the images from the PDF. Does it still work on Xamarin as well.

Comment: Is the file you want to render from local storage or are you downloading and displaying?

Comment: Just a local file. I just wanted to keep check of the user usage of the application. So when they launched the application, I can store it somewhere and send to server later for monitoring the usage .

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions available that work on Android before api level 21.

You can use [Xamarin.PDFView](https://github.com/jenasubodh/Xamarin.PDFView) which uses pdf.js to show the pdf file.

Another option is [Xamarin.PdfView.Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.PdfView.Android/) library which is a wrapper for java pdf view library.

One more option is [MuPDF-for-Xamarin-Android](https://github.com/asimmon/MuPDF-for-Xamarin-Android) which is a wrapper for java MuPDF library.